# What kind of a connection do realtime native mobile apps use?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, websocket, 3g

I want to build a *realtime **native mobile app**,* which will be **mostly operating through 3g.**

I wonder how I can connect my back end (whatever that might be) to my native mobile app.

I looked into websockets (specifically SockJS with Node), but it seems that it won't **operate well through a 3G connection**, and also theres no native android client for the websockets.

If not websockets, what then? 
p.s: I've heard of [MQTT over websockets](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-over-websockets-with-hivemq/), is that a valid option?

Comment: most of the apps and games use json for data in network with http

Comment: By that you mean http request, as in a restfull api for example? But that is not realtime..!

Comment: that is at realtime if server is quick responsive

Comment: yes but also theres a lot overhead because of the http headers. Remember thats meant for a native mobile app so data and battery usage is a criteria.

Comment: Have you had a look at Autobahn|Android (http://autobahn.ws/android/) which provides a native, open source Android WebSocket implementation? (Full disclosure: I work for Tavendo, who do the main development on the project.)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the real time multi-player api. I think this is what you're looking for.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer

Comment: This is absolutely great for a mobile game. I will certainly take a look at it, but perhaps I've used a wrong title. My bad. I'm not currently building a mobile game, but I do want a realtime connection such as the ones that mobile games use.